# Function based index on a partitioned table

Tags: oracle, function, indexing, partition

I would like to create a simple function based index like: to_char('column') on a huuuge partitioned table!

The question: how to do it faster and smarter? Just create index on a table or Partition by partition or.. ?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the machine/version you have, you would probably be better off if you create the index unusable, then rebuild it partition by partition, using 'parallel x' to go faster.